# Kenwood stereo stuck with only "Standby" after battery died

Tags: audio

My car battery died, and now my KCD-BT268U only shows "Standby" when I turn it on.  No choice to see the Tuner, Aux, et cetera.

How do I get it back?  I really  miss listening to the radio!

Answer (score 1):

On [pg4 of the owners manual](http://manual.kenwood.com/files/B5A-1860-00.pdf), it shows the following:

[image]

If you look at step #3, it shows *how to get into STANDBY* mode, then shows you how to get out of it in step #3.5. Press and hold the button with the magnifying glass and return arrow to exit. Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: I did this.  I can press SRC to turn it on and off again.  It starts up with "Standby" showing.  When I press the volume, the screen goes blank.  There is a tiny transient "BT" in the lower left of the screen, but this goes away as well.  I did read the manual.

Comment: Did you make sure you didn't blow any fuses. There are two power leads to the stereo. One is continuous +12vdc while the other is switched. Ensure both are working correctly.